# Using RegEx in CDO.Message with Classic ASP

Tags: regex, vbscript, asp-classic, cdo.message

I'm working with the CDO.Message object in ASP VB, and I'm attempting to utilize VB Regular Expressions to process my form field (textarea) text before it's sent as a (non-HTML) email.

What I'm trying to do is to filter out any \r or \n (or combination) that occur without a preceding period.  However, none of the Regular Expressions is of effect in the text in the email, although I've tested the code in an online Regex tester, and it worked fine.

However, I can add chr(13) in the strings, and it shows in the email.

I would prefer to not use HTML, if possible.  Would anyone have any suggestions as to why the Regex is not working?
Thanks

Here's the regex below:

```
<%strGoals = Request.Form("Goals")
                        Set regEx = New RegExp
                        regEx.Global = True
                        regEx.IgnoreCase = True
                        regEx.Pattern = "(([^\.])(\r\n|\r|\n)+)"


                        set matches = regEx.Execute(strGoals) 
                        If matches.Count > 0 Then
                        For Each Match in matches 
                        varGoalsResults = matches.item(0).submatches(0)
                        Response.write("<div style=""background-color:#f00;"">"&varGoalsResults&"</div>")
                        Next
                        Else
                        response.write("no matches")
                        End If

                        strGoals = Trim(regEx.Replace(strGoals, "$2"))

         strBody = strBody & "Goals: " & chr(13) & Request.Form("Goals") & chr(13) & chr(13)
%>

<!--#include virtual="SendEmail.asp"-->
```

Here is the code for SendEmail.asp:

```
<%
Set ObjMail = CreateObject("CDO.MESSAGE") 

ObjMail.From = strFrom

ObjMail.To = strTo

ObjMail.Cc = strCc

ObjMail.Subject = strSubject

'ObjMail.BodyPart.ContentMediaType = "multipart/alternative"

If strFormat = "HTML" Then
    strHTMLStart = "<html><head><style type=""text/css"">body {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}</style></head><body>"
    strHTMLEnd = "</html></body>"
    ObjMail.HtmlBody = strHTMLStart & strBody & strHTMLEnd
Else
    ObjMail.TextBody = strBody
End If




ObjMail.Send 

Set ObjMail=nothing
%>
```

Comment: Have you tried `regEx.Multiline = True`?

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, but that didn't work.

Comment: Have you actually tried testing your `RegExp` using `.Matches` to see if it actually detects anything with that pattern?

Comment: Thanks - yes, I did, and I've edited my original post to show the code.  It did detect the strings, but the replace did not occur.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `regEx.Global = False` it should work.

Comment: No, I tried that, and it didn't work.  Thanks for your suggestion.